# AJAX request for multiple values from multiple divs with same class

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So, lets say that we have this structure:

```
  <div id='allTempLinkHolder'>
    <div class='tempLink'>Value</div>
    <div class='tempLink'>Value 2</div>
    <div class='tempLink'>Value 3</div>
 </div>
```

How i can submit all of the different values of .tempLink with post ajax, for example to post them to fetch.php ?
Thanks!

Comment: submit them as what key/value setup? WHat have you tried????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you simmply want an array sent:

```
var values = $.map($('.tempLink'), function(el, idx) {
    return $(el).text()
})

$.post('fetch.php', { values: values}, function(data) {
        /* do something with return data*/
})
```

Comment: what does that mean? what do you see in console inspecting request?

Comment: you can't make a post like that on fiddle.net, there is no url 'fetch.php' there

Comment: send it to a real php and receive with `$_POST['values'];`  will be an array

Comment: I'm testing it on localhost, i just copied it there so i can show it to you

Comment: works fine in another fiddle i made. Have to send in json in fiddle but is pretty much the same  http://fiddle.jshell.net/WLe2p/

Comment: when i test it , and set the function on success to console.log the returned data, there is nothing in the log...

Comment: what are you returning? Look at the request itself in console, can see what is sent, status etc

Comment: i'm using this post  `$.post('testajp.php', { values: values}, function(data) {
       $('.result').html(data);
})
`
And from my testajp.php i have echoed "Working", but nothing its not returned ...

Comment: but are you sending anything back from the php page??

Comment: ye, i have echo "Working";
I have this ajax to run on button click, this can be a problem or its okey, its on document ready, then on button click

Comment: and what do you see in request body within console?? find the whole request, that includes all the headers, params etc, and response

Comment: Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
values[] data1
values[] data2
values[] data3
Source
values%5B%5D=data1&values%5B%5D=data2&values%5B%5D=data3

Comment: hm? its just `<?php
echo 'Working';
?>`

Comment: Okey bro, the problem was that the button which i used to triger the event was in a form, and this divs too, so it is now working perfect :) Thanks for your time man!

Answer (score 1):

```
var params;

$(".tempLink").each(function(){
  params=$.extend({}, params,   { "tmplink[]" , $(this).text() }  );
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: params,
    success: function() {
      //Success code here
    }
});
```

in PHP you will receive it in an array `$_POST["tmplink"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/htKRf/3/

```
var links = []

// Put all the tempLinks into an array. 
$.each($('.tempLink'), function (index, element) {
    links.push($(element).text());    
});

// Post it to the url.
$.post('fetch.php', JSON.stringify(links), function() { console.log("SUCCESS"); });
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
var values=[];
$(".tempLink").each(function(){
    values.push($(this).text());
});

$.post({
    url: 'yourPhpScript.php',
    data: {values:values},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

In your `php script` use

```
$arr = $_POST['values'];

$value1=$arr[0]; // value
$value2=$arr[1]; // value1
$value2=$arr[2]; // value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a separate Ajax call for each div

```
 $("div.tempLink").each(function(index, elem) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "my url" + "?param=" + this.text(),
        success: function() {...
        }
    });
});​
```

or a single call with array of values

```
var values = new Array();
$("div.tempLink").each(function(index, elem) {
    values.push(this.text());
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url",
    data: JSON.stringify(values),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {...
    }
});​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

First you would use a jQuery class selector to collect the values into a suitable data structure. I wasn't sure how you wanted to do that, so I used a javascript map and linked the position in the original list to the value of the text `{"link1":"value1","link2":"value2",...}`.

```
var map={};
$(".tempLink").each(function(index) {
    map["tempLink"+index] = $(this).text();
});
```

To figure out the usage and syntax of $.ajax see [the jquery ajax api ref.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "fetch.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(map),
    dataType: "...", //The type of data you're expecting the server to respond with
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {},
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {}
});​
```

When your ajax call returns, if it's successful the success callback fires, otherwise error fires. You can use these to handle the data your server responds with, or let the user no that the request failed.